# Excel not deleting all selected rows

Tags: excel, find

I have a spreadsheet with a couple hundred rows, and some of the cells contain the text "N/A". I'd like to delete the full row of any cell that has "N/A" in it.

My first thought was to use Find All and then once all the relevant cells are selected, I can do Ctrl - and select "entire rows". However this usually leaves a bunch of cells with "N/A". Why is this?

Comment: How are you selecting the "#N/A" now?

Comment: Why not just filter and sort

Comment: Hey @BruceWayne I'm actually not looking for "#N/A" (like you would get from a vlookup that doesn't find anything) but just regular N/A. I'm selecting it now by going Ctrl F, Find All, selecting one and hitting Ctrl A, which selects all cells that have N/A

Comment: @urdearboy because some of the cells have contents besides the N/A . For instance I want to be able to delete the rows containing cells "N/A" and "N/A, BC" and "SF, N/A"

Comment: "I'd like to delete the full row of any cell that has "N/A" in it" means i'd like to be able to delete (for example) the full row of any of the following cells:
1. xxN/Axx 2. N/Axx 3. xxN/A since they are all cells with N/A in them. Sorry if this is the wrong terminology.

Also, these are all text. No formula results.

Comment: VBA or excel only solution? In excel, you can a helper column with a wild card. Then filter your helper column with matches and delete those rows. In VBA, you have many options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Insert a column (or use last available blank column).
2. Use equation `IFERROR(SEARCH("N/A", A2),"No Match")` where I am
   assuming `Column A` has your strings that *may* contain **N/A**
3. Drop Equation down to used range
4. Filter your new helper column and remove `No Match`
5. Delete rows of visible cells

---

Output below. Any numeric value in `Column B` means a match of **N/A** was found.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped .